# Implement A*-Search as Breadth-First-Search / Depth-First-Search

Tags: algorithm, search

For an assignment in "Introduction to artificial intelligence" I need to solve the following question:

```
Let f(n) = c1*g(n) + c2*h(n) be an evaluation function, where c1,c2 be constants.
1. Define c1,c2,h(.),g(.) such that A* with this evaluation function is bfs.
2. Define c1,c2,h(.),g(.) such that A* with this evaluation function is dfs.
```

For BFS I had the following idea:
Let `g(n)` be the cost from the start node to the current node and `h(n)` the estimated cost from current node to goal.
If I set `c2 = 0` it should actually be Breadth First Search.

For DFS I thought of setting `c2 = 0` and `c1 = (-1)`

Any ideas, tips or feedback you can give me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answers are the ones that are expected. However I think the question is a bit wrong because I don't find it possible to make BFS and DFS (in the terms I understand them).

The problem is that both DFS and BFS don't care about the path lengths. They just care about the node order.

Your BFS solution is actually a uniform-cost search (or dijkstra algorithm) which is an improvement to basic BFS.

Your DFS solution expands the farthest node, which is not how the actual DFS  (with stack) works.

*The answers will be right if there was somewhere stated that the arc cost is always the same.*

Comment: ok thx for the answer, I also find the question a bit weird, thats why i decided to ask it here. But yeah thx for the help :)